# Recursively Find and return Minimum and Maximum in array

Tags: java

The function gets **only 2 parameters**: 
arr of numbers and n represent number of them in array.
I need **recursively** find and return the Minimum and Maximum in array.
In minimum **complexity of 3n/2** comparison. 
**The code below returns MIN only. How should I make it so it returns both MIN and MAX?**

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int A[] = { 1, 4, 45, 6, -50, 10, 2 };
        int n = A.length;

        // Function calling
        System.out.println(findMinMaxRec(A, n));

    }

    public static int findMinMaxRec(int A[], int n) {
        // if size = 0 means whole array
        // has been traversed
        if (n == 1)
            return A[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            return Math.min(A[n - 1], findMinMaxRec(A, n - 1));

        // The program NO return min and max (both)
        return Math.max(A[n - 1], findMinMaxRec(A, n - 1));
    }
}
```

Answers:

```
-50
45
```

Comment: Your code can't work, you'll never go at the last return, and just run the first iteration of your loop each time ^^and only check the first item

Comment: And, there is no question, or no problem in you post, so ... ?

Comment: i know there is problems. I wrote above the code it no return both min and max...

Comment: So write it, edit your post and tell what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two versions, on in ascending order, and one in descending order :

```
static int[] findMinMaxRecDesc(int[] A, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return new int[]{A[0], A[0]};
    }
    int[] recResult = findMinMaxRecDesc(A, n - 1);
    return new int[]{Math.min(A[n - 1], recResult[0]), Math.max(A[n - 1], recResult[1])};
}

static int[] findMinMaxRecAsc(int[] A, int n) {
    if (n == A.length - 1) {
        return new int[]{A[n], A[n]};
    }
    int[] recResult = findMinMaxRecAsc(A, n + 1);
    return new int[]{Math.min(A[n], recResult[0]), Math.max(A[n], recResult[1])};
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 4, 45, 6, -50, 10, 2};
    int[] result = Arrays.toString(findMinMaxRecAsc(array, array.length))
    System.out.println(result); // [-50, 45]
}
```

And the method `findMinMaxRec` is called `n+1` times, so it's linear, like a for-loop

Comment: The method should get only 2 parameters and work recursively.